# Strange kerning in any terminal with Droid Sans font on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, kerning, monospace

Terminal looks very strange when I set Droid Sans as a default font in:
[Terminator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc5uV.png),
[lxterminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5uMY.png) (clickable)

[image: Terminator]

[image: lxterminal]

I have ubuntu 14.14 and use Cinnamon 2.8.6

---

**EDIT:** Setting "Droid Sans Mono" in the terminal helped, but it's not a solution if you want to set non-monospace font, so the question still be opened.

Comment: Give a bit more information (e.g a screenshot might help).

Comment: Terminator: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc5uV.png, Lxterminal: http://i.stack.imgur.com/U5uMY.png. They are clickable in the original post. Sorry that I didn't note that

Comment: Just an idea: You said you use "Droid Sans" - have you tried to use Droid Sans Mono? The former is not a Monospace font, the later is.

Comment: Yep, that helps (http://i.imgur.com/zcE13hQ.png). Thank you so much. But anyway it's strange that non-monospace font looks in the terminal like that.

Comment: Google is your friend. http://superuser.com/questions/357571/customize-text-editor-and-terminal-to-use-non-monospaced-fonts-without-the-horri

Comment: Since that helped, I'd be happy if you could accept my solution (since you are new: press the tick besides my post below) and give an upvote :-). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Droid Sans" is not a monospace font, so instead you should use "Droid Sans Mono".